# Wordpress, excluding pages with pre_get_posts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i want to exclude all wordpress pages from all wordpress queries.

My idea to solve this problem was to set the posttype in `pre_get_posts`

```
function meta_filter_posts( $query )
{
  $query->set( 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'meta_filter_posts' );
```

But it doesn't work. I get no results. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function exclude_pages($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
       $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages');
```